Как корректно перенести цепочку методов на разные строки?
Стандартной практикой в LINQ является запись методов "цепочкой" - один за другим, каждый метод на своей строке:
var nodes = Enumerable
        .Range(0, nodesCount)
        .Select(z => new Node(z))
        .ToArray();

Помимо LINQ, подобный подход применяется и для цепочки вызовов обычных методов, для упрощения чтения и восприятия и уменьшения длины строки. Однако с ними уже не все так логично и интуитивно, как с LINQ, на мой взгляд.
Прошу подсказать, как, к примеру, разложить следующую цепочку на 3-4 строки:
return CreateFromCsFiles(OpenFileHelper.OpenCodeFile(File.ReadAllText(pathToCsprojFile)).ToArray());

Как ни пробовал, все равно получается каша. Заранее спасибо!

Если речь про написание своего, то ИМХО, должно быть что-то такое: return Some.FromCsFiles("...", "...");, где Some - это более понятное название того, что создается, а ".." - это чисто пути к файлам, всякие OpenCodeFile - это уже внутренности этого метода. Если речь про переписывания данной строки кода, без возможности что либо изменить, то вынесите все внутренности CreateFromCsFiles за его пределы (var files = OpenFileHelper...), ну а дальше уже переносите как хотите. Ну то есть, избавляйтесь от вложенности, код будет в разы понятней тогда.

Благодарю за ответ! Это строка - часть инициализации достаточно сложного объекта с древовидной структурой на основе данных, считанных из файлов на диске. CreateFromCsFiles - фабричный метод для создания объекта, OpenFileHelper.OpenCodeFile - метод для его парсинга. Создать отдельные переменные не проблема, просто думал что есть допустимый варинт комбинации множественных вызовов обычных методов, наподобии того, как это делается в LINQ. В общем-то тут ничего сложного не происходит, простая процедура. Можно ли сказать, что для обычных методов подобный "Method chaining" нежелателен?

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface

Спасибо за ссылку! Если я правильно понял посыл, то вызов методов по цепочке наоборот является желательным, там где это возможно. Гладное это грамотно организовать, например с помощью способа с методом расширения из ответа ниже.

Можно ввести дополнительные переменные:
var text = File.ReadAllText(pathToCsprojFile);
var array = OpenFileHelper.OpenCodeFile(text).ToArray();
return CreateFromCsFiles(array);

В некоторых языках есть специальный оператор конвейера - pipe operator. Например, в F# таким является |>. Если интересно, можно посмотреть его применение в документации.
За неимением такового, в C# можно сделать метод расширения.
public static class PipeExtension
{
    public static TOut Pipe<TIn, TOut>(this TIn input, Func<TIn, TOut> fn)
    {
        return fn(input);
    }
}

Код взят из доклада Pipeline Oriented Programming (pdf по ссылке), ScottWlaschin. Есть и видео от автора с таким же названием.
С его помощью код можно записать так:
return File.ReadAllText(pathToCsprojFile)
    .Pipe(OpenFileHelper.OpenCodeFile).ToArray()
    .Pipe(CreateFromCsFiles);


Спасибо за ответ! Интересная идея, нужно обдумать...

Без лямбда-выражений не работает - нужно писать так же, как в LINQ: .Pipe(x => x...). Но так отчасти даже лучше - сразу видно где результат предыдущего метода, что он из себя представляет, и можно подставлять его в выражения. Оценить бы еще накладные расходы такого трюка...

@JamesBond https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1599630/373567

@JamesBond - работает и без -лямбда-выражений. И в LINQ можно писать без них. Естественно, только в том случае, если сигнатура вызываемого метода совпадает с сигнатурой делегата. / Приведите точные сигнатуры методов, чтобы можно было понять, что не так.

Предложенный в вашем варианте делегат принимает и возвращает по одному значению. ReadAllText принимает строку (путь) и возвращает строку (открытый файл), OpenCodeFile принимает строку (открытый файл) и возвращает список (извлеченные данные), CreateFromCsFiles принимает этот список и возвращает коллекцию экземпляров класса. Вроде все совпадает... Попытка убрать лямбды вызывает ошибку CS0411

@JamesBond - вместо написания такого длинного комментария просто скопируйте объявления методов и вставьте в вопрос.

@AlexanderPetrov получилось только что) С другими методами, которые принимали и возвращали ровно один объект. Для тех же, что принимают или возвращают коллекции, нужно написать перегрузку для Pipe, которая будет принимать IEnumerable и возвращать IEnumerable. Спасибо еще раз)
